# It says invalid datatype

Tags: sql, database, oracle

This is my SQL script; when I try to run, I get an error:

> ORA-00902: invalid datatype

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE TranInfo 
(
    T_ID CHAR(11) NOT NULL, 
    T_Amount NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
    T_Time Time, 
    T_Date Date, 
    C_ID CHAR(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(T_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(C_ID)REFERENCES Customer (C_ID)
);
```

What is wrong? Please help me - I can't find it.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-A3C0D836-BADB-44E5-A5D4-265BA5968483

Answer (score 2):

There's no `TIME` built-in datatype. `DATE` includes a time component.